# java super for field

Tags: java, super

Why `super` have no effect on `i` field in class `C` ?
The output is `012`, but why not `321`, since class `B` extends class `C` ?

```
public class C {
      protected int i;

      public C(int i){
           this(i,i);
           System.out.print(this.i);
           this.i=i;
      }

      public C(int i, int j) {
           System.out.print(this.i);
           this.i=i+j;
      }

      public C(){
              this(1);
              System.out.print(i);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
             C c=new C();
      }
}

public class B extends C{
       public B(){
              super.i=3;
       }



       public static void main(String[] args){
            C c=new B();
       }
}
```

Comment: Is it really nesseccary to post your question several times just with different titles?

Comment: same question today

Comment: @Andreas: Well, it is not the same question, it's a follow-up.

Comment: @Thilo not really. Anything related to the `super` keyword happens after the printing and has absolutely no effect on the outcome.

Comment: Try printing `super.i`/`this.i` after setting it to `3` in `B`'s constructor

Comment: I wonder that noone noticed the output `012` he mentioned actually isn´t the ouput beeing produced by the code given.

Answer (score 2):

`super.i` just refers to `this.i` (or simply `i`) because class `B` does not declare its own version of `i`, so it inherits the field from `C` already.

```
   public B(){
          super.i=3;   // the super here does not do anything
   }
```

The first thing a constructor needs to do is invoke one of the super constructors. So this is equivalent to:

```
   public B(){
          super();
          i=3;
   }
```

As you can see, the code in the superclass `C` is executed before `i` is set to 3. That's why it prints the old value.

Answer (score 1):

`super` can be used for accessing overridden methods. In your scenario `i` is an inherited member of B.

If you override a method in B that was defined in C, you can call it from B by using the super keyword.

Comment: consider rewording "is used" to "can be used" or "is being used".

Answer (score 0):

It´s quite simple. That´s what is happening:

```
B Constructor is called.

B doesn´t have an explicit super constructor call- so implicity call super().

C() Constructor is called -> call C(int)

C(int) Constructor is called -> call C(int,int); 

C(int, int) is called. print i. i only has the default value yet so print ->0

C(int, int) does increment i by j, which at this point is 1+1 = 2

C(int) Constructor callback, as C(int, int) is done, print i = 2

C(int) sets i = 1 and prints i = 1.

B() callback as C() is done. set instance variable i to 3.
```

As you can see you have a different output as `021` and that´s everyone that does happen.

I don´t know what your initial intention was, but `super` can have different meanings.

In the constructor you usually access a parents constructor with `super`.

by doing `super.i` you are only accessing the instance variable `i` of the parent class.

you could, by doing `super.testMethod()` call an method `testMethod` from the parentclass